Is there a way (in M) to generate a date/time stamp for the earliest refresh date as opposed to the latest? - Power BI
I am pulling from an underlying dataset that I do not have access to and there is no date/timestamp for the entry of data into this dataset.
I am trying to come up with a way to add one post-hoc in power query, but functions such as fixedlocalnow() still change when I refresh the data source.
What I am looking for is effectively an earliest refresh date for each row of data, as opposed to a latest refresh date.
Normally I can get by tweaking solutions I have found by googling, but I have only managed to find a single person online with a similar problem to mine (from 2022) and they were essentially told it cannot be done.
What I would like to happen is



data columns
date/timestamp




data loaded into PBI on second refresh
datetime2


data loaded into PBI on second refresh
datetime2


data loaded into PBI on first refresh
datetime1


data loaded into PBI on first refresh
datetime1



Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

If there is something unique that identifies the data in each refresh (id # or something similar), perhaps you could separately create a calendar table that includes the relevant id#'s matched to the corresponding dates.

You could attempt to use the Power Apps for Power BI visualization and write the data back to a table or workbook - you would need to identify when a row is "new". Alternatively introduce a staging area between the data source and the PBI. Load to the PBI from Staging instead of directly. You would add the date in the staging area. Both suggestions are flawed in that you would be storing duplicates of the source data  but you could minimize the impact if you store just the ID (as suggested by Ron Rosenfeld)

I agree with @CHill60. You can't do this without a data store that holds the date values you want to use. If you were using PowerQuery within Excel, you could load your query to a sheet, create a new query that loads directly from that sheet (instead of the query behind it) and results in a table of dates per key, then modify your original query to merge them together. In PowerBI, however, you don't have a data store so you must introduce yet another piece or two to your solution.

Thank you @Ron Rosenfeld, CHill60, and JSmart523. I see the limitation more clearly now and I think I will be able to use an excel sheet in conjunction with my data I'm pulling in to keep a stored set of ID+date pairs
